# SD.h not compatible with other libraries in Arduino/C++ environment

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having some very weird issues using the following hardware elements:

- [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)
- [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields)
- GPS receiver
- Accelerometer
- Barometer

I wanted to off-load the sensor readings to an SD card as needed, but before I can even code the SD functions, the mere inclusion of the `SD.h` library renders my code useless.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <SD.h>

/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 3(rx) and 4(tx).
*/

//For baraometer
#include <Wire.h>

#define BMP085_ADDRESS 0x77  // I2C address of BMP085

const unsigned char OSS = 2;  // Oversampling Setting

// Calibration values
int ac1;
int ac2;
int ac3;
unsigned int ac4;
unsigned int ac5;
unsigned int ac6;
int b1;
int b2;
int mb;
int mc;
int md;

// b5 is calculated in bmp085GetTemperature(...), this variable is also used in bmp085GetPressure(...)
// So ...Temperature(...) must be called before ...Pressure(...).
long b5;
//End of baraometer

//ACcelerometer
// These constants describe the pins. They won't change:
const int xpin = A1;                  // x-axis of the accelerometer
const int ypin = A2;                  // y-axis
const int zpin = A3;                  // z-axis (only on 3-axis models)
//end of accel

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial nss(3, 4);

static void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps);
static bool feedgps();
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);

void setup()
{
  //Make sure the analog-to-digital converter takes its reference voltage from
  // the AREF pin
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);

  pinMode(xpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ypin, INPUT);
  pinMode(zpin, INPUT);

  //Barometer
  Wire.begin();
  bmp085Calibration();

  //GPS
  Serial.begin(115200);
  nss.begin(57600);

  Serial.print("Testing TinyGPS library v. "); Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Sizeof(gpsobject) = "); Serial.println(sizeof(TinyGPS));
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Sats HDOP Latitude Longitude Fix  Date       Time       Date Alt     Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum");
  Serial.println("          (deg)    (deg)     Age                        Age  (m)     --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail");
  Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}

void loop()
{
  //Accelerometer
  Serial.print( analogRead(xpin));
  Serial.print("\t");

  //Add a small delay between pin readings.  I read that you should
  //do this but haven't tested the importance
    delay(1);

  Serial.print( analogRead(ypin));
  Serial.print("\t");
  //add a small delay between pin readings.  I read that you should
  //do this but haven't tested the importance
    delay(1);

  Serial.print( analogRead(zpin));
  Serial.print("\n");  // delay before next reading:






  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();

  // Every second we print an update
  while (millis() - start < 1000)
  {
    if (feedgps())
      newdata = true;
  }


  //barometer
  float temperature = bmp085GetTemperature(bmp085ReadUT()); //MUST be called first
  float pressure = bmp085GetPressure(bmp085ReadUP());
  float atm = pressure / 101325; // "standard atmosphere"
  float altitude = calcAltitude(pressure); //Uncompensated caculation - in Meters

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temperature, 2); //display 2 decimal places
  Serial.println(" C");

  Serial.print("Pressure: ");
  Serial.print(pressure, 0); //whole number only.
  Serial.println(" Pa");

  Serial.print("Standard Atmosphere: ");
  Serial.println(atm, 4); //display 4 decimal places

  Serial.print("Altitude: ");
  Serial.print(altitude, 2); //display 2 decimal places
  Serial.println(" M");

  Serial.println();//line break
  //end of barometer



  gpsdump(gps);
}

static void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  static const float LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  print_int(gps.satellites(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES, 5);
  print_int(gps.hdop(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP, 5);
  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 9, 5);
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 5);
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);

  print_date(gps);

  print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 8, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_speed_kmph(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_SPEED, 6, 2);
  print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
  print_int(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0UL : (unsigned long)TinyGPS::distance_between(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON) / 1000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  print_float(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, 51.508131, -0.128002), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_str(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON)), 6);

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  print_int(chars, 0xFFFFFFFF, 6);
  print_int(sentences, 0xFFFFFFFF, 10);
  print_int(failed, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  Serial.println();
}

static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
  else
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0)
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  feedgps();
}

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
    sz[len] = 0;
        if (len > 0)
          sz[len-1] = ' ';
    for (int i=7; i<len; ++i)
        sz[i] = ' ';
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1);
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(" ");
  }
  feedgps();
}

static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  int year;
  byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  unsigned long age;
  gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
  if (age == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE)
    Serial.print("*******    *******    ");
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d   ",
        month, day, year, hour, minute, second);
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  feedgps();
}

static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  feedgps();
}

static bool feedgps()
{
  while (nss.available())
  {
    if (gps.encode(nss.read()))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// Stores all of the bmp085's calibration values into global variables
// Calibration values are required to calculate temp and pressure
// This function should be called at the beginning of the program
void bmp085Calibration()
{
  Serial.write("\n\nCalibrating ... ");
  ac1 = bmp085ReadInt(0xAA);
  ac2 = bmp085ReadInt(0xAC);
  ac3 = bmp085ReadInt(0xAE);
  ac4 = bmp085ReadInt(0xB0);
  ac5 = bmp085ReadInt(0xB2);
  ac6 = bmp085ReadInt(0xB4);
  b1 = bmp085ReadInt(0xB6);
  b2 = bmp085ReadInt(0xB8);
  mb = bmp085ReadInt(0xBA);
  mc = bmp085ReadInt(0xBC);
  md = bmp085ReadInt(0xBE);
  Serial.write("Calibrated\n\n");
}

// Calculate temperature in deg C
float bmp085GetTemperature(unsigned int ut){
  long x1, x2;

  x1 = (((long)ut - (long)ac6)*(long)ac5) >> 15;
  x2 = ((long)mc << 11)/(x1 + md);
  b5 = x1 + x2;

  float temp = ((b5 + 8)>>4);
  temp = temp /10;

  return temp;
}

// Calculate pressure given up
// calibration values must be known
// b5 is also required so bmp085GetTemperature(...) must be called first.
// Value returned will be pressure in units of Pa.
long bmp085GetPressure(unsigned long up){
  long x1, x2, x3, b3, b6, p;
  unsigned long b4, b7;

  b6 = b5 - 4000;
  // Calculate B3
  x1 = (b2 * (b6 * b6)>>12)>>11;
  x2 = (ac2 * b6)>>11;
  x3 = x1 + x2;
  b3 = (((((long)ac1)*4 + x3)<<OSS) + 2)>>2;

  // Calculate B4
  x1 = (ac3 * b6)>>13;
  x2 = (b1 * ((b6 * b6)>>12))>>16;
  x3 = ((x1 + x2) + 2)>>2;
  b4 = (ac4 * (unsigned long)(x3 + 32768))>>15;

  b7 = ((unsigned long)(up - b3) * (50000>>OSS));
  if (b7 < 0x80000000)
    p = (b7<<1)/b4;
  else
    p = (b7/b4)<<1;

  x1 = (p>>8) * (p>>8);
  x1 = (x1 * 3038)>>16;
  x2 = (-7357 * p)>>16;
  p += (x1 + x2 + 3791)>>4;

  long temp = p;
  return temp;
}

// Read 1 byte from the BMP085 at 'address'
char bmp085Read(byte address)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(BMP085_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(address);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(BMP085_ADDRESS, 1);
  while(!Wire.available()) {};
  return Wire.read();
}

// Read 2 bytes from the BMP085
// First byte will be from 'address'
// Second byte will be from 'address'+1
int bmp085ReadInt(byte address)
{
  unsigned char msb, lsb;

  Wire.beginTransmission(BMP085_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(address);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(BMP085_ADDRESS, 2);
  while(Wire.available()<2)
    ;
  msb = Wire.read();
  lsb = Wire.read();

  return (int) msb<<8 | lsb;
}

// Read the uncompensated temperature value
unsigned int bmp085ReadUT(){
  unsigned int ut;

  // Write 0x2E into Register 0xF4
  // This requests a temperature reading
  Wire.beginTransmission(BMP085_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write((byte)0xF4);
  Wire.write((byte)0x2E);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Wait at least 4.5 ms
  delay(5);

  // Read two bytes from registers 0xF6 and 0xF7
  ut = bmp085ReadInt(0xF6);
  return ut;
}

// Read the uncompensated pressure value
unsigned long bmp085ReadUP(){
  unsigned char msb, lsb, xlsb;
  unsigned long up = 0;

  // Write 0x34+(OSS<<6) into register 0xF4
  // Request a pressure reading w/ oversampling setting
  Wire.beginTransmission(BMP085_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0xF4);
  Wire.write(0x34 + (OSS<<6));
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Wait for conversion, delay time dependent on OSS
  delay(2 + (3<<OSS));

  // Read register 0xF6 (MSB), 0xF7 (LSB), and 0xF8 (XLSB)
  msb = bmp085Read(0xF6);
  lsb = bmp085Read(0xF7);
  xlsb = bmp085Read(0xF8);

  up = (((unsigned long) msb << 16) | ((unsigned long) lsb << 8) | (unsigned long) xlsb) >> (8-OSS);

  return up;
}

void writeRegister(int deviceAddress, byte address, byte val) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress); // Start transmission to device
  Wire.write(address);       // Send register address
  Wire.write(val);           // Send value to write
  Wire.endTransmission();    // End transmission
}

int readRegister(int deviceAddress, byte address){
  int v;
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
  Wire.write(address); // Register to read
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(deviceAddress, 1); // Read a byte

  while(!Wire.available()) {
    // waiting
  }

  v = Wire.read();
  return v;
}

float calcAltitude(float pressure){

  float A = pressure/101325;
  float B = 1/5.25588;
  float C = pow(A,B);
  C = 1 - C;
  C = C /0.0000225577;

  return C;
}
```

Granted, right now, it is merely a conglomeration of multiple example sketches, but they work. I get a sampled reading from the accelerometer, the GPS unit and the barometer once a second. However once I simply add the line `#include <SD.h>` to the sketch, it fails to run correctly. The serial monitor does not display anything. I have similar versions of the above sketch (omitted as they are much lengthier), but I get the same result: either jumbled text or nothing on the Serial monitor. If I comment out the line that include the SD.h library, everything works fine....

Are there known issues with the `SD.h` library or conflicts? And yes, I am NOT using the necessary pins for the SD access (digital pin #4) for my sensor connections....

UPDATE:

I at least figured out it has something to do with the SoftSerial (SoftSerial.h) library and the use of the SoftSerial object (which I called nss). I can load all libraries and get everything to work if I do not call nss.begin. Is there a reason why that would conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was out of memory.  Having the Serial go unresponsive like that is a common symptom.  This [link](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory) ultimately is what I used to trace and conclude my memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to check the `Arduino` site, on the `SD` documentation ([here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD)) there's a mention that the communication between the `microcontroller` and the `SD card` uses `SPI` (documentation [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI)) which takes place on `digital pins` `11`, `12` and `13`. I wouldn't be surprised if this was the source of your problems with the `Serial` monitor.

Reading some comments in `Sd2Card.h`, it might be tricky to get your setup to work properly:

```
/**
 * Define MEGA_SOFT_SPI non-zero to use software SPI on Mega Arduinos.
 * Pins used are SS 10, MOSI 11, MISO 12, and SCK 13.
 *
 * MEGA_SOFT_SPI allows an unmodified Adafruit GPS Shield to be used
 * on Mega Arduinos.  Software SPI works well with GPS Shield V1.1
 * but many SD cards will fail with GPS Shield V1.0.
 */
```

Even if you put `MEGA_SOFT_SPI` to a non 0 value, you'd probably still fail to pass the `(defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__)||defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__))` check.

I would suggest trying your same sketch without the `TinyGPS` to try to pinpoint the issue.

Also, check out [this sketch](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=120653.0) it seems to be doing something similar to what you're doing, maybe you can fix yours based on what's done here.

Comment: "Mega Arduinos" in that comment refers to a specific Arduino kit based on the ATmega1280 or ATmega2560 CPU. So no -- of course that won't work.

Comment: Pins 11, 12 and 13 are unused, so that cannot be it.  Though note I am using the WiFi Shield which also uses pins 11, 12 and 13 for its own purposes, but the SD card I am using is built into the WiFi Shield.  However note, I am not even using the SD card itself (haven't gotten that far) but simply loading the library...

Comment: @WildBill what I suspect is that either `sd.h` or a file it includes, `sdfat.h` or `sdfatutil.h` `#define` a value that messes with your other libraries. Did you try to change the `#include` order?

Comment: I did modify the order.  I placed SD.h in every possible order.  I've yet to dig into the individual .h files, was hoping it wouldn't come to that.  I'm a bit green and unsure what to look for there.....

Comment: @WildBill from what I saw (don't have an arduino board here) the header file has 2 ways it could cause troubles: a) defines that are conflicting with other libraries or b) objects that affect your board by changing or writing on pins... from what I can see, the objects created by default by the lib seem pretty harmless, I hope someone can provide you with a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use pin 4 for CS and change the MOSI, MISO and SCK pins in the library SD in Sd2card.h, hope you will get rid of the problem